# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, listview

#It keeps giving this error I don't know why someone can help me?#

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecordListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList <Model> recordList;

    public RecordListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Model> recordList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.recordList = recordList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {


        return recordList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return recordList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtnome,txttelefone,txtdataNascimento,txtEmail,txtprovidencia;
}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
        if (row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(layout,null);
            holder.txtnome=row.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
            holder.txttelefone=row.findViewById(R.id.edtCelular);
            holder.txtdataNascimento=row.findViewById(R.id.edtDataNascimento);
            holder.txtEmail=row.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
            holder.txtprovidencia=row.findViewById(R.id.edtProvidencia);
            holder.imageView=row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }


        Model model =recordList.get(position);
        holder.txtnome.setText(model.getNome());
        holder.txttelefone.setText(model.getTelefone());
        holder.txtdataNascimento.setText(model.getDataNascimento());
        holder.txtEmail.setText(model.getEmail());
        holder.txtprovidencia.setText(model.getTelefone());
        byte[] recordImage=model.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(recordImage,0,recordImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return row;


    }
}
```

public class Model {
private int id;
private String nome;
private String telefone;
private String DataNascimento;
private String Email;
private String providencias;
private byte[]image;

```
public Model(int id,String nome,String telefone,String dataNascimento,String Email,String providencias,byte[] image){
    this.id=id;
    this.nome=nome;
    this.telefone=telefone;
    this.DataNascimento=dataNascimento;
    this.Email=Email;
    this.providencias=providencias;
    this.image=image;



}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getDataNascimento() {
    return DataNascimento;
}

public void setDataNascimento(String dataNascimento) {
    DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getProvidencias() {
    return providencias;
}

public void setProvidencias(String providencias) {
    this.providencias = providencias;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque um breakpoint nesta linha:

`Model model =recordList.get(position);`

e veja se de fato "holder" está diferente de nulo. Ao que parece, por conta de holder estar nulo é que ocorre o erro.

Uma dica: o site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ é em português. Já o https://stackoverflow.com/ é a versão em inglês.

Comment: Mano ta se referindo ao meu txtnome